# How to remove this section from being enclosed in <li> tags

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system

I couldn't find the "actual" backend of this page (http://www.drink-driving-lawyers.com.au/pleading-guilty-or-not-guilty) where I could remove the `<li>` and `<ul>` tags that make the first paragraph bulleted.

> The decision to plead guilty or not guilty is the most important decision that you make in a drink driving case. It is very important if defending a drink driving charge to have all the information from your lawyer. Further down the page there are a number of defences to drink driving charges.

We're using Wordpress as a CMS and whenever I go to the backend of that page via WP Admin, that section is not bulleted and is not enclosed in `<ul>` and `<li>` codes. And yet when you check the source, it shows up as:

```
<ul class="postul">
<li class="first-child last-child">
<p>The decision to plead guilty or not guilty is the most important decision that you make in a drink driving case. It is very important if defending a drink driving charge to have all the information from your lawyer. Further down the page there are a number of defences to drink driving charges.</p>
<p>You have to weigh up the chance of winning a defence of your drink driving charges with the extra cost and the possibly worse penalty you may receive.</p>
```

What file do I need to adjust to remove these `<ul>` and `<li>` tags?

Comment: You don't mind using jQuery to solve this problem? Or you'd insist on a server-side solution?

Comment: I would definitely love to learn both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Client-side

You could easily include this bit either in your `Appearance > Editor > footer.php` (or header.php), and solve the problem, by getting rid of `<li class="first-child last-child">`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var myList = $(".postul > li > *").first(); //find the first element after li
$(myList).unwrap(); //remove what's containing it without removing itself
});
</script>
```

Reading the comments, it must be pretty easy to understand what I am trying to do. But let's go line by line:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

Wait until the DOM is [ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
var myList = $(".postul > li > *").first();
```

I would like to have a variable named `myList`. This variable indicates (reading from * to the beginning) = *whatever* there is under `li`, where the `li` is within another element that has a class called `postul`.

*asterisk* = whatever element (`<div>`,`<p>` or whatever!)

Also, `first()` as it says, returns only the [first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) result with that condition (thus the rest of your items in the page are not affected).

In other words, it says find this:

```
<element class="postul">
    <li>
        <something> <!-- I WANT THIS! --> 
        <something> <!-- and NOT this --> 
    </li>
</element>
<element class="postul">
    <li>
        <something> <!-- NOT this either --> 
    </li>
</element>
```

And lastly:

```
$(myList).unwrap();
```

After finding my element now, [unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) it. Which means:

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM,
>   leaving the matched elements in their place.

Which would then lead our example code to be:

```
<element class="postul">
        <something> <!-- its parent is removed but it's still here --> 
        <something> <!-- this is NOT affected --> 
</element>
<element class="postul">
    <li>
        <something> <!-- NEITHER this is affected --> 
    </li>
</element>
```

This then should lead to what you are looking to achieve.

### Server-side

It's difficult to say where it is exactly coming from (while not having access to your back-end), but it definitely does impact every post you have, hence it's coming from your server-side. This merely depends on your template and how posts are structured, but you could look into `single.php` or any other post related PHP page in your template.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I tried the "Client Side" solution and while it did remove the bullet from that first paragraph, it also removed the bullets from the list below - which shouldn't be the case. This is actually how it was at first but then I adjusted a CSS file and the bullets for the list at the lower section finally appeared - but so did that unwanted bullet on the first paragraph. I guess it really has to be solved via the server side. Will keep looking into the files.

Comment: Opps, edited! Please check and let me know. It should work now :)

Comment: Hmmm... The edited script actually worked for the page indicated. I put it on the footer.php file which is a common file. However, when I checked other pages, it did not solve the same issue on this page: http://www.drink-driving-lawyers.com.au/licence-restoration-interlock-removal. Not sure why that is considering that the footer.php file also serves this other page. So I guess I really need to do it via the client side.

Comment: Ah I see. That's because in your other page, there's a `<div>` right after `<li>`, and not a `<p>`. Edited my code again, please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks man! It finally worked!... I know this is too much and you may not answer. But can you elaborate on the codes as if explaining to a newbie? This one in particular: `var myList = $(".postul > li > *").first();`

Comment: No worries, I am glad it did. I added little bit more of explanation, please ask if anything :) Enjoy coding!

Comment: Thanks again! The explanation was thorough and the additional links were really helpful :)